# Trying to make a progress bar that animates between two ints that change frequently

Tags: android, progress-bar, objectanimator

I have a little guess-the-hex-value game that I'm making for my first Android app that I am trying to display the percentage correct your guess is with a progress bar. I have the progress bar working fine, but I'm having trouble getting the animation to work.

Here is my animation:

```
protected ObjectAnimator progressAnimator;
```

then on OnCreate..

```
progressAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(percentageBar, "progress", percentageCorrectOld, percentageCorrectNew);
progressAnimator.setDuration(5000);

//i'm not sure where I should be starting this animation?
progressAnimator.start();
```

And here I have a textChanged Listener that detects when the hex guess is updated where I set the `int percentageCorrect`

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

//sets the old percentage correct, which is set to 0 on onCreate
percentageCorrectOld = percentageCorrect;

//calculates the percentageCorrect using color comparison deltaE equation (irrelevant)
percentageCorrect = 100 - (int) ((deltaE / 375.5955) * 100);

//sets the newly calculated percentageCorrect to the new value
percentageCorrectNew = percentageCorrect;

//sets the text of the progress bar to the new value
percentageBarText.setText(""+percentageCorrect);

//sets the progress of the bar
percentageBar.setProgress(percentageCorrect);
}
```

Basically I am not sure where I should be starting the animation? Starting it in the `afterTextChanged` listener seems wrong as it would just restart the animation over and over.. (also it doesn't work, tested it). Starting it on `onCreate` doesn't work, either. I am getting the correct `percentageCorrectOld` and `percentageCorrectNew` values in the `afterTextChanged` listener, but the animation just won't play when I need it to.

Any help? I am really unsure of the best way to use this animation. Thanks!